# Entity framework code first many to many

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first, ef-code-first

I've searched everyhwere but couldn't find an answer...

First, I have created a many to many relationship using code first which worked well. Each person can be in multiple clubs and each club can have multiple members. The `ClubPersons` table has been created in the DB.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Then I need to add the creator of the club which is also a person (one to many):

```
public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Creator { get; set; }
}
```

After doing this, the `ClubPersons` table in the DB has gone, replaced by a `Club_Id` in the `People` table and `Person_Id` and `Creator_Id` in the `Clubs` table.

As you can see, this won't work and it gives me the following error when I try to add person/club:

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Person_Clubs_Source' of the relationship 'Test.Models.Person_Clubs' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

My question is what's the proper way to define such relationship in code first? Many to Many to One

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following method to your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().HasRequired(x => x.Creator) //or HasOptional
                               .WithMany() //Unidirectional
                               .Map(x => x.MapKey("Creator")) //FK column Name
                               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

That will keep EF from assuming a bidirectional relationship on Club.Creator <=> Person.Clubs